# Set id of a button or div by variable value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing code where the total number of buttons being used will be decided at run time. Buttons `id`(s) need to be different/unique for every button. Because the amount of buttons can be variable, I think some kind of loop would be needed and `id`(s) should be set by another variable.

These lines should be what appears in html :

```
<button class="btn" value="1" id="1">button 1</button>
<button class="btn" value="2" id="2">button 2</button>
```

....and so on.

Here is my JS so far :

```
var total_button = 4;
var btn_id       = 1;
var btn_value    = 1;

for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = 
      '<button class="btn" id="' + btn_id + '" value="' + btn_value + '">button 1</button>';
    btn_id++;
    btn_value++;
}
```

Expected result:

```
<div id="list">
    <button class="btn" value="1" id="1">button 1</button>
    <button class="btn" value="2" id="2">button 2</button>
    <button class="btn" value="3" id="3">button 3</button>
    <button class="btn" value="4" id="4">button 4</button>
</div>
```

What should I do to implement different/unique `id`(s) ?

Comment: Tell us what is the issue you are facing when you implemented the above code.

Comment: It looks like you're just forgetting to wrap strings in quotes...

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: not java..its javascript @epascarello

Comment: @NitinSen you tagged it Java, was pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```js
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var totalButtons = 4;

for (var i = 0; i < totalButtons; i++) {
  list.innerHTML += `<button id="id-${i}">Button ${i}</button>`;
}
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: thanks @iacobalin , this code is working what i have required. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to create DOM elements:

```
var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
button.innerHTML = "YOUR TEXT"
document.body.appendChild(button);
button.setAttribute("id","btnid" + i); // i is any varibale
```

The id can be a variable value. Use a loop or any other that you desire.

Comment: Run your code, to make sure it works, before posting.

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov surely, I am new to the community and hence did not know. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
    list.innerHTML += 
      `<button class="btn" id=${i}  value=${i}>button ${i}</button>`;
}
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```